# Database structure for "follow" feature similar to twitter?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a similar feature as Twitters "follow" feature but wondering a bit about how you would create a database structure for something like that. Say we have a user table like this:

> id, username

And then a posts table that looks like this:

> id, userid, post, date

What i want to do is to let a user follow other users, and then in a stream get their posts. So i'm guessing there should be a follow table. Where you can insert which user follows which user. But then how do i query a stream out of this? If user 1 follows user 2 and 3. I want to make a query like

```
SELECT posts FROM $peopleIfollow ORDER BY date
```

But as you see the above example is not a valid query, how can i gather "follow"-information and query the results? Or more what is the structure i should be looking into to achieve this? Should followers be put in an array and is it possible to have an array in a query?

Comment: This is a many-to-many relationship in SQL. There are many users following many users. There is a bunch of literature online about this, but the basics would be a two column table. The first being the user who is following the user in the second column. Then to find out who user 1 is following you would do something like SELECT follow_id FROM followTable WHERE user_id = user1; That would return rows full of user id's of the users user1 is following.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick and simple solution that I can think of...

```
following(follower_id, following_id)
```

Then you'd get posts something like

```
SELECT *
FROM post_table
LEFT JOIN following 
    ON following.following_id = post_table.userid
WHERE following.follower_id = ?
LIMIT 0, 20;
```

Where ? is the ID of the current user. This would then join the tables and pull the posts of the person that the follower is following. You could also throw in an order by date.

This SQL statement could be vastly improved, but that's a quick and simple idea for ya.